# Server tag not well formed - sending 2 parameters onClientClick from Rad grid

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a radGrid containing a button view column, and I want to send 2 values which are columns in the radgrid when the view is clicked, the VoitureID and TypeID. 
I have this code but it is not working. Nothing is happening.

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Rapport" OnClientClick='OpenViewRepport("<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IdVoiture") %>","<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IdType") %>"); return false;' />
```

It keeps giving me a "server tag not well formed" error.

Comment: I have a hunch that this is because you have quotes within quotes. "IdVoiture" is an example.

Comment: but IdVoiture is the string name . i tried it and it gave me this :
"Input string was not in a correct format."
IdVoiture is returning "<%" only and IdType is not returning anything

Comment: and this is my javascript function 
     function OpenViewRepport(VID,TID) 
{                                 
   var oWindow3 = $find("RadWindowManager1").open("ViewForm.aspx?IdVoiture="+VID+"&IdType="+TID, null, null, 750, 600);            
}

Answer (score 0):

```
"<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IdVoiture") %>"
```

In this line, you close the quote at DataItem," then write IdVoiture then open the quote again after IdVoiture and close it again after %>...Basically you wrote "<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, " and then you wrote ") %>"

I know this is a problem, and that is one of the reasons why ASP.NET MVC is superior; because it does not suffer from these limitations. One way to get around this problem is to split the contents of the quotes into something like:

```
"<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem," + var_that_has_quotes_in_it + ")%>"
```

Comment: yeah but this line code cannot be added  to the OnClientClick of the button, because i cannot create a variable in that .